# How to get return value in this case? (Java FX)

Tags: javafx, jersey, jersey-client

I'm writing part of a cross-platform application, where we mostly use REST (jersey) and Hibernate to communicate between systems. I'm new to JavaFX, but my side of the program should use it to get input values from users. Here is how the code flow would look:

```
public class startingClass{

...

public void startingMethod(Payload payload){

//send REST requests to different places with different payloads, like:
Response response = Utility.sendPostRequest(URI, payload2);
something = response.readEntity(something.class)
//more processing with the returned values
...

}}
```

In one of the places where I sent a request:

```
@Path("something")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  + ";charset=UTF-8")
public class Resource{

...

@POST
@Path(something)
public Response doSomething(Payload payload) {
    //show JavaFX window with text fields and an okay button
    JavaFXClass.launch(JavaFXClass.class);

   /* THIS IS WHERE I would need to get back the input values somehow */

   //payload3 has the input values I need to send back
   return Response.entity(payload3).build();
}}
```

The JavaFX class extends application and and overrides the (void) start method where I put together the window I want to show and after the button click (if inputs are okay) I close the window.

So the idea is that the startingMethod would have to wait, until the response comes back (maybe return with some default values, if the user doesnt type in anything for a minute - what would be the elegant solution for that?) with the input values. This would guarantee the sync.

If I use more REST or database saves inside the JavaFX class then I can't be sure the values are there by the time I wanna use them in the startingMethod (probably not) and it's probably a really bad looking solution anyway.

What could I do? I dont know much about callback methods in javafx, can those help me here? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that you are trying to show a window on the server side. Maybe you need to rethink your design, or maybe even take some time to get a better understanding of how all your system components fit together

Comment: We chose REST for this because that's what we know somewhat.(Plus it's doable on a Raspberry 3) This application is an IoT demo with sensor readings periodically coming in. (The 3 of us are not programmers per se, just electrical engineering students.)

Comment: That makes sense, but your design should be more like 1) show client window. 2) User inputs to window. 3) client app sends input to REST server. 4) REST server sends response 5) client acts on response

Comment: The startingMethod gets called when a threshold is reached based on the sensor inputs (a component needs to be replaced). Then the operator of this demo system has to input information about the replacement component, which we can use elsewhere. But this is not really the main point here. Even if we have a better system design, my problem is still there that unless we run this JavaFX class in a main method, I'm not sure how to get back input value from it (to the doSomething method). That's how most of the examples work I could find.

Comment: So if I have this correct, the Raspberry will be some sensory component that sends singnals to the REST server. When the singnals come into the server, some user needs to make some inputs on a window based on that input? And then the response is sent back to the Raspberry?

Comment: Well the need for user based input is caused by the REST request coming in, but the REST payload will not influence what the user types in. The startingClass will be on the RPi3, the Resource class (+ jersey application) on a laptop, acting as a coorporate ERP system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I moved the JavaFXClass into the Resource class. Meaning Resource class extends Application, overrides start, etc. In the doSomethingMethod I call launch in a try-catch block, catch the IllegalStateException if needed and call start() instead (also in a try-catch block). The textfield input values are stored in a global variable after.

Also in the start() method I have`Platform.setImplicitExit(false);`
so the doSomethingMethod() can be called multiple times without a problem, starting the javaFX window. It's not a pretty solution.